# KNeighbors Regressor .predict() function giving suspiciously perfect results when trained with weights='distance'?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

If I train a KNeighborsRegressor (via scikit-learn) and then want to compare its predictions against the target variable, I can do that this way:

```
#Initiate model
knn = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=8)

#Define independent and target variables
X = df[['var1', 'var2', 'var3']]
Y = df['target']

#fit the model and store the predictions
knn.fit(X, Y)
predicted = knn.predict(X).ravel()
```

If I were to compare them I can see this model is far from perfect, which is expected:

```
compare = pd.DataFrame(predicted,Y).reset_index()
compare.columns=['Y', 'predicted']
compare.head(3)
```

Returns:

```
+------+-----------+
| Y    | predicted |
+------+-----------+
| 985  | 2596      |
+------+-----------+
| 801  | 2464      |
+------+-----------+
| 1349 | 1907      |
+------+-----------+
```

**If I do the exact same thing except I weight neighbors by distance, the predict() function is returning the target variable EXACTLY.**

```
#Initiate model
knn_dist = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=8, weights='distance')

#fit the model and store the predictions
knn_dist.fit(X, Y)
predicted2 = knn_dist.predict(X).ravel()

compare = pd.DataFrame(predicted2,Y).reset_index()
compare.columns=['Y', 'predicted2']
compare.head(3)
```

Returns identical columns:

```
+------+------------+
| Y    | predicted2 |
+------+------------+
| 985  | 985        |
+------+------------+
| 801  | 801        |
+------+------------+
| 1349 | 1349       |
+------+------------+
```

I know the predictor isn't really perfect like this implies, and can prove that with cross validation:

```
score_knn = cross_val_score(knn, X, Y, cv=ShuffleSplit(test_size=0.1))
print(score_knn.mean())
>>>>0.5306705590672681
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Per request, here's the first five rows of the relevant columns in my dataframe:

```
| ID | var1     | var2     | var3     | target |
|----|----------|----------|----------|--------|
| 1  | 0.363625 | 0.805833 | 0.160446 | 985    |
| 2  | 0.353739 | 0.696087 | 0.248539 | 801    |
| 3  | 0.189405 | 0.437273 | 0.248309 | 1349   |
| 4  | 0.212122 | 0.590435 | 0.160296 | 1562   |
| 5  | 0.22927  | 0.436957 | 0.1869   | 1600   |
```

Comment: hi.  perhaps showing a few rows of your data would be helpful.

Comment: Added above in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you train the model on the whole dataset and then you predict using the same dataset.

> knn_dist.fit(X, Y)
>
> predicted2 = knn_dist.predict(X).ravel()

**The perfect performance here is a textbook case of overfitting.
For every point in X, the weighting for that point will be essentially 1**

---

Next, when you use `cross validation` you see that the model is not so perfect. 
You should always use cross-validation especially in the case where you are trying to predict (regression) a target variable.

Also, for regression problems **do NOT** use `cross_val_score`  without specifying the `scoring` argument.

You can alternatively use `cross_val_predict`. See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html)

If you add some information (like the dimensions of X) I could help more.

Comment: So the distance weighting makes sense, since every xi lands on a trained point, the weighting for that point will be essentially 1, so it'll predict perfectly. thanks. 

Can you clarify the second comment though? `cross_val_score` gives you R-squared scores, `cross_val_predict` gives you predicted values for the target variable. 
Did you mean to say use `cross_val_predict` instead of `knn.predict()` ?

Comment: Yes. But in your example, you did not specify the `scoring` in `cross_val_score `. Thus, either define the `scoring ` argument in `cross_val_score` or use `cross_val_predict ` and then calculate the R^2

Comment: @Cobra `cross_val_score` by default will use the `score()` method of supplied estimator (regressor in this case, which defaults to R-squared), so there is no harm in using it without `scoring`.

Comment: Thanks. @VivekKumar you are correct, I don't think I've done anything wrong with `cross_val_score` here, but @seralouk properly noted that I should use only `cross_val_predict`, not `.predict()`

Comment: exactly no problem in this case but I wanted to stress the difference.